# Character limit countdown for multiple textareas on the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

At the moment I am trying to create essentially the same type of countdown on twitter textareas. It does work for the first textarea but it then duplicates the same amount of characters remaining for all posts when I start typing in the first texarea.

What I need to know is how do I get the characters remaining for only the current textarea?

HTML:

```
<textarea name="comment" class="inputField newComment">@'.$post['username']." ".'</textarea>
<span class="countdown"></span>
```

jQuery:

```
function updateCountdown() {

    var remaining = 140 - $('.newComment').val().length;
    $('.countdown').text(remaining + ' characters remaining');

    if(remaining < 0){

        $(this).siblings('.postComment').hide(500);

    }else{

        $(this).siblings('.postComment').show(500);
        if(remaining <= 10){
            $(this).siblings('.countdown').css("color","red");
        }else{
            $(this).siblings('.countdown').css("color","black");
        }
    }
}

$('.newComment').change(updateCountdown);
$('.newComment').keyup(updateCountdown);
```

Comment: `$(this)` is the `textarea`, and your snippet already has the _exact_ code necessary to reference the related `.countdown` `span`.

Comment: the first two lines of your function are referencing ALL elements that match those classes, alter that to only select the current one using `this`

Comment: I know but I have already tried these solutions but unfortunately it shows nothing when I start typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this,

HTML

```
    <textarea name="comment" class="inputField newComment" data-limit=20></textarea>
<span class="countdown"></span>
<textarea name="comment" class="inputField newComment" data-limit=20></textarea>
<span class="countdown"></span>
```

JS

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('textarea').on("propertychange keyup input paste",

    function () {
        var limit = $(this).data("limit");
        var remainingChars = limit - $(this).val().length;
        if (remainingChars <= 0) {
            $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, limit));
        }
        $(this).next('span').text(remainingChars<=0?0:remainingChars);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qMbdW/3/

Comment: Nice one, appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

My version is a little longwinded, but it works and doesn't require a data-limit attribute (or any other attribute) on the textarea. In my case, I was struggling against an ancient version of jQuery and CMS with its own form builder and limited access to the HTML of the page.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="counter">myTextArea</div>
<textarea id="myTextarea" rows="2" cols="30">   </textarea>

<div id="counter2">myTextArea2</div>
<textarea id="myTextarea2" rows="2" cols="30"></textarea>
```

And here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // set the IDs for the text areas and counters
    // handy for aliasing long, CMS-generated IDs
    var myTextarea = 'myTextarea';
    var counter = 'counter';
    var myTextarea2 = 'myTextarea2';
    var counter2 = 'counter2';

    $('#' + myTextarea).keyup(function () {
        var charLimit = 150; 
        var remainingChars = charLimit - $(this).val().length;
        if (remainingChars < 0) {
            // trim input, if necessary
            var tlength = $(this).val().length;
            $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, charLimit));
            var tlength = $(this).val().length;
            remain = parseInt(tlength);
            $('#myTextarea').text(remain);
        }
        $('#' + counter).text('(' + remainingChars + ' characters left)');
    });
    $('#' + myTextarea2).keyup(function () {
        var charLimit = 150; 
        var remainingChars = charLimit - $(this).val().length;
        if (remainingChars < 0) {
            // trim input, if necessary
            var tlength = $(this).val().length;
            $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, charLimit));
            var tlength = $(this).val().length;
            remain = parseInt(tlength);
            $('#myTextarea2').text(remain);
        }
        $('#' + counter2).text('(' + remainingChars + ' characters left)');
    });
});
```

Here's the JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jamesnotjim/k9fzoytp/